# How to alter the color of cells if they are a certain other color?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a short Macro to change cells of a given colour to another colour in a workbook. This code throws no errors however it simply does nothing.

I have already tested the colour codes to see if they are correct using `MsgBox ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.color`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Recolour()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim OldColour As Variant
    Dim NewColour As Variant
    Dim Cell As Range

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Y457")
    OldColour = 128
    NewColour = RGB(134, 38, 51)

    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells

            If ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = OldColour _
                Then _
                Set ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = NewColour _
            Else

        Next Cell

    Next Sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is probably something simple and daft however I need to ask.

Comment: When you do `Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Y457")` you link `rng` to range A1:y457 of the worksheet that is active in that moment. But later on you do a loop trough worksheets and trough `rng` when `rng` is already linked, you actually you are looping same cells **in the same worksheet** every time.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Thank you for this. I have reviewed my code and changed it to:

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set Rng = Range("A1:BZ600")
        
However it still does as you say, only looking at whatever sheet was last active when the workbook was saved, why is this??? :?

Comment: Because the hierarchy of objects. When you say just `Range("A1")` you are referencing `A1` of ActiveSheet. But if you do `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")` you are referencing `A1` of a specific worksheet. In your loop, you should activate every sheet before linking `rng`. Anyways, read something about hierarchy in Google, like https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/macros-explained-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DisplayFormat` is read-only.  If you want to change the property, you need to drop `DisplayFormat`.  Also, if you are using `For each Cell`, then you should refer to `Cell`, not `ActiveCell`.

```
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        If Cell.Interior.color = OldColour Then 
            Cell.Interior.color = NewColour
        End if    
    Next Cell
Next Sheet
```

Answer (score -1):

You only need to `Set` object variables in VBA, your `if` statement is also problematic. Try:

```
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        If ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.color = OldColour Then 
            ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.color = NewColour
        End if    
    Next Cell
Next Sheet
```